# How to increase the size of the bar labels using ggplot2 in a facet_grid() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to create a bar plot using the facet_grid() function in ggplot2. But, I cannot be able to increase the size of the bar labels of this plot. There's no error message when I run the code.
I am trying to identify what did I do wrong? Why is this happening?

Here are my codes -

```
df = data.frame(Year = c("2008", "2009", "2010"),
                Tot_Marriage = c(278, 271, 275),
                Preg1 = c(57, 63, 62),
                Preg2 = c(199, 154, 55))

df

df2 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c("Tot_Marriage", "Preg1", "Preg2"), names_to = "Indicators", values_to = "Number")

Plot3 = ggplot(df2) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = Indicators, y = Number ), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", col="black", fill="bisque")+
    theme()+
    facet_wrap(.~Year)+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=20, angle=30, hjust=1 ),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=20),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size=24, face="bold"),
          strip.background = element_rect(color="black", size=1),
          plot.title = element_text(size=22, face="bold", hjust=0.5, vjust=1),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")+
    scale_x_discrete(name="Indicators",
                     limits = c("Tot_Marriage", "Preg1", "Preg2"),
                     labels = c("Tot_Marriage" = "Marriage", "Preg1"="Pregnancy (Y1)", "Preg2" ="Pregnancy (Y2)"))+
    geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=1), aes(y=Number, x=Indicators, label=(Number), size=10, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5))+
    ggtitle( "duration")

Plot3
```

I got the following figure -

[image]

For more clarification, I want to increase the size of the "Tot-Marriage", "Preg1", "Preg2" columns value.

Comment: Change `axis.text.x=element_text(size=20...` to `axis.text.x=element_text(size=30...`

Comment: Hi!

I actually want to increase the size of the following columns value - "278", "57", "199", "271", "63"....

Hope you've got my concern.

Comment: I am struggling mainly with the following line of codes -

`geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=1), aes(y=Number, x=Indicators, label=(Number), size=10, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5))`

Comment: OH, you want the numbers `278`, `57`, ... bigger? Don't put constants inside `aes()`. Change to `aes(y=Number, x=Indicators, label= Number), size=12, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5)`. Note the `)` for `aes()` is now after `label = Number)`. The `size`, `hjust`, and `vjust` are outside `aes()`.

Comment: `print("Many thanks!") `

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to increase the size of the labels on top of the bars:

```
df = data.frame(Year = c("2008", "2009", "2010"),
                Tot_Marriage = c(278, 271, 275),
                Preg1 = c(57, 63, 62),
                Preg2 = c(199, 154, 55))

df

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Tot_Marriage", "Preg1", "Preg2"), names_to = "Indicators", values_to = "Number")

Plot3 = ggplot(df2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Indicators, y = Number ), stat = "identity", col="black", fill="bisque")+
  theme()+
  facet_wrap(.~Year)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=20, angle=30, hjust=1 ),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=20),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=24, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(color="black", size=1),
        plot.title = element_text(size=22, face="bold", hjust=0.5, vjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_discrete(name="Indicators",
                   limits = c("Tot_Marriage", "Preg1", "Preg2"),
                   labels = c("Tot_Marriage" = "Marriage", "Preg1"="Pregnancy (Y1)", "Preg2" ="Pregnancy (Y2)"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Indicators, y = Number, label=Number), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, size = 8) +
  ylim(limits = c(0, 300)) +
  ggtitle( "duration")

Plot3
```

Output:

[image]